# Need assistance with converting const char* word to a lowercase version of it

Tags: c

I am trying to convert a a const.char to a lowercase version of that word. Here is the code I currently I have:

```
int i=0;
char DuplicateArray[45];
int sizevalue=0;
Node* NodePointer=NULL;
unsigned int hashval=0;
int counter=0;
sizevalue=strlen (word);

strncpy(&DuplicateArray[counter], word,sizevalue);//word is the const char pointer.
DuplicateArray[sizevalue+1] = '\0';
hashval=hash(DuplicateArray);//function I call to determine hash value
while ( DuplicateArray[i] != '\0' )
{
    DuplicateArray[i] = tolower(DuplicateArray[i]);    
    i++;
}
```

With this code I have, however, I am not able to make the characters in the array lower cased. Does anyone have any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How is `DuplicateArray` declared ?

Comment: Like this:
char DuplicateArray[45];

Comment: How are `counter` and `i` initialized?

Comment: Can I assume `word` is declared as `const char *word`?

Comment: yes it is a const char. *word

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're either misunderstanding arrays and the `&` and `[]` operators, or the other various "small" mistakes in your code (that all result in UB as far as I can tell) make your program misbehave. This [works](http://ideone.com/efwFg1):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char* uppercase = "UpPeRcAsE";

    char duplicateArray[45];
    int uppercaseSize = strlen(uppercase);

    // copy uppercase into duplicateArray
    strncpy(duplicateArray, uppercase, uppercaseSize);

    duplicateArray[uppercaseSize] = '\0';
    int i = 0;
    while (duplicateArray[i] != '\0')
    {
        duplicateArray[i] = tolower(duplicateArray[i]);    
        i++;
    }

    printf("Before: %s, after: %s\n", uppercase, duplicateArray);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Btw, you better indent and format your code properly, use lowercase and mixed case identifiers consistently and read up about strings more - the code is **horrible** as currently standing.

Comment: ok...thats good to know...so its probably something else thats not ticking thats causing me to go gray is what your saying?

Comment: @user2014904 It may be... As I explained, you seem to have some misunderstanding about arrays or strings or both.

Comment: Cool. thanks man!I appreciate. Bitter sweet. Didnt find the problem, but what I was doing wasnt totally off either. And thanks for the tip on formatting and what not. Truth hurts, but better know now then later..

Answer (score 0):

If the encoding is Ascii, do it in binary. The difference is in bit 6, which is 0 in uppercase letters and 1 in lowercase letters. You can easily find do it by subtracting 32 in decimal, or just flip the sixth bit. For example, character A is 1000001 (0x41) and character a is 1100001 (0x61).

Comment: Nah, advising OP to hack with non-portable hardcoded values instead of standard library macros is plain wrong.

Comment: H2CO3 is on a downvoting spree, somebody stop him. But actually you don't need to do binary, you can do tolower, or simply check ranges and use  the fact that ("Z"-"A")+"a" = "z"

Comment: @Dmitry I'm not on a downvoting spree, it's just that both answers are wrong.

Comment: Correct. `("Z"-"A")+"a" = "z"` is neat.

Comment: There is a difference between a "wrong" answer and a "useful" answer. Also, in C there is no "right" answer.

Comment: you need to rethink your views on life. An analogy is always better than no answer.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void dotolower(const char *cstr)
{
    char *str = (char*)cstr;

    while (*str) {
        *str = tolower(*str);
        ++str;
    }    
}

int main()
{
    char mystr[] = "HELLO";
    dotolower(mystr);
    puts(mystr);    

    return 0;
}
```

as an example

Comment: and yes, this example is evil because the function lies about not touching the string passed.

Comment: which you should never do (because it's a constraint violation therefore it invokes undefined behavior).

Comment: yes, thats exactly why I used mystr[] rather than mystr*, mystr* would, and actually did crash when I tested this program. This problem isn't safe altogether. But an analogy is an analogy.

Comment: You can, but as depth of pointers increases, that solution makes code messy. I believe doing such things does not offer a great demonstrational value.

Comment: I don't think two <stdio.h> headers are necessary.

Comment: int puts(char*) is inside stdio.h.